# Error when using calc() and CSS v-bind() with Tailwind

Tags: css, vuejs3, tailwind-css

How to bind using css classes? for example pb-4

```
  div {
    width: calc(v-bind('a') - 3px);
  }
```

what I want:

```
  div {
    width: calc(v-bind('a') - pb-4 + 'px');
  }
```